# Enquiry about reportViewer taking parameters from a form

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, reportviewer

I'm quite new to using `ReportViewer`. I have a problem that I do not know how to solve.

I have a Date `TextBox` and a Location `TextBox`.  My problem is that, when the user keys in the date and location, how do I display the same data in the `ReportViewer`. Below are some screenshots for better understanding. Any help will be appreciated.

Please let me know if more details are required.

[image: This is the report.rdlc for the reportviewer. The AllocationDate and the LocationName shown in the pic below will show the Date and Location when the user key in the data.]

[image: This is the Windows Form that has the Textboxes to key in the Date and Location]

Comment: What's your criteria? Do both fields required or either one is fine? IMHO, Having a 'Submit' button is better.

Comment: It's better to be both fields is required. Yep I forgot to add a Button. Any idea how to do that to show?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you'll add a `ShowButton` button to your Form. However, you can use TextBox event (e.g. Focus Lost, Text Changed etc) instead of button click event.

```
   private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime allocationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(allocDateTextBox.Text);
        string   locationName   = locationTextBox.Text;

        //You can create as many datasources matching the name of DataSet in your report
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1");
        rds.Value = getData(String.Format("Select * from myTable where theDate={0} AND Location={1}", allocationDate, locationName));

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        //add as many datasources created above
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

   private DataTable getData(string query)
   {
      //Select new record from database based on the new query with the new criteria
      //return the record as DataTable, DataSet or Collection of object
   }
```

Comment: Is there any references to add for the ReportDataSource??

Comment: why did you ask? I think this is what you need `using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
`

Comment: that will be for window application. Tag your question with the right tag - winform or asp.net

Comment: my bad, now I have tagged winform.

Comment: Excuse me, but could explain about this line, "rds.Value = getData(String.Format("Select * from myTable where theDate={0} AND Location={1}", allocationDate, locationName));" I'm unclear about this. Could you show me a simpler example?

Comment: that's just querying the database. you have to replace it with your data access method. how are you populating your report with data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16340/discussion-between-codingbiz-and-philemon)